Thrust difference between GE90-115B and RR Trent XWB-97 vs. related aircraft MTOW difference?
Looking at Boeing 777-300ER and Airbus A350-1000 engines at Wikipedia:



Aircraft
B777-300ER
A350-1000
difference




Type certificate
No. EASA.IM.A.003
No. EASA.A.151



Engine model
General Electric GE90 115B
Rolls-Royce RR Trent XWB-97



Engine parameters
2-shaft  Fan Dia=3.3m  4LP-9HP compressor  2HP-6LP Turbine
3-shaft  Fan Dia=3.0m  8IP-6HP compressor  1HP-2IP-6LP Turbine



Engine datasheet
No. IM.E.002
No. EASA E.111



MTOM
351 534 kg
322 000 kg
-8.40%


MLW
251 290 kg
236 000 kg
-6.08%


take-off thrust
513.95 kN
431.5 kN
-16.04%


TO thrust / MTOM
1.46 m/s2
1.34 m/s2
-8.34%


TO thrust / MLW
2.05 m/s2
1.82m/s2
-10.60%



The A350 is 8.4% lighter at MTOW but has a substantially lower  take-off thrust (-16%):

How is reduction of thrust feasible in larger MTOW aircraft whilst not compromising on go-around climb gradient and other parameters related to application of take-off Thrust?

Why are the thrust reduced in newer aircraft models as compared to older models ?



You're not comparing the same thrust number. The XWB-97 is 97,000 lb takeoff and 83,100 lb max continuous. The GE90-115B is 115,540 lb takeoff.

I fixed the thrust value as suggested by @user71659. The relative difference in thrust is still larger than in MTOW, so the question remains valid.

@Bianfable we were working on this at the same time, I largely overwrote your edits with mine. Our percentage differed, because I took the 777 as reference, you took the A350. The result is that my percentage are somewhat smaller.

First off, for the same number of engines, the missed approach criteria (thrust-to-weight ratio) as derived from the regulations depend on the lift-to-drag ratio, which in turn depends on the wetted area (smaller for the 1000 due to its smaller fuselage, which cancels out the difference in aspect ratio more or less). Also, the missed approach climb segment is the least constraining element (see diagram below); and that's not taking into account the advancements in flap design (see this Q&A and this Q&A).


Via https://www.fzt.haw-hamburg.de/pers/Scholz/HOOU/AircraftDesign_5_PreliminarySizing.pdf

(Also see the pdf for the equations.)
Second, the 1000 received a trailing edge modification increasing the wing area (reason in this Q&A); this reduces the wing loading compared the 300ER, which works for the take off performance.
The big question is how does it achieve the same cruise performance, e.g. the A330 is slower than the 777, but that's not the case here.
Here being built lighter (OEW by 12 tonnes) means cruising higher sooner with the same payload, and the newer engines run for longer on the same fuel.
